# How can I remove an eventListener, AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, event-listener

On the first frame of my timeline, I have the following action script:

```
stop();

ClickTAG.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, manageMouseOver, false, 0, true);   

function manageMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void
{   
    play(); 
}
```

I am not really familiar with AS, but this accomplishes what I want, i.e., is to start the timeline on mouseOver. However, if you repeatedly mouseOver and Off the swf later, this can interrupt the animation later in the timeline, e.g., it will skip through timeline delays and restart the movie after the last frame.

How can I remove this listener or prevent it from operating after the movie reaches the second frame? I less than basic understanding of AS, so thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

```
function manageMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void{   
     event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, manageMouseOver);
     play(); 
}
```

This simple code is able to remove an event right after it's being called.

Comment: It's `removeEventListener`, not `removeEvent`. Also, don't assume that the current event target was the object that added the event listener in the first place, it can vary. In OPs case, it should be `clickTAG.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, manageMouseOver, false)`, exactly as written (An event listener is identified using **both** the listener function and the `useCapture` flag, the third parameter to both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`). The same listener function may be added at both phases separately.

Comment: @amn "Also, don't assume that the current event target was the object that added the event listener in the first place" => Please read carefully the AS3 doc for Event. `currentTarget` is ALWAYS the object on which you called `addEventListener`. Thanks for noticing the typo on `removeEventListener`, though.

Comment: @cubanlink Validate answer, maybe =) ?

Comment: @blue112, you are right, I got confused there. Won't happen again. You still need to include `, false` at the end of the call - otherwise you are removing a non-existing listener (no listener was added for capture phase).

Comment: @blue112 Oh my :-) I am embarassed.

Answer (score 1):

Handy way to removing event listeners in AS3

```
function manageMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee);

   play(); 
}
```

For more details [arguments.callee docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/arguments.html)

Comment: thanks that was handy when tossing the function in the addListener assignment vs calling a external method/handler.

Answer (score 1):

Removing listener from the object itself in your case:

```
stop();

ClickTAG.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, manageMouseOver, false, 0, true);   

function manageMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void
{   
    ClickTAG.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, manageMouseOver)
    play();
}
```